# DataFrame.hist() shape not looking correct

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

For the dataset that I am using, it is available on Kaggle at this [link](https://www.kaggle.com/stackoverflow/so-survey-2017)

I am just importing the .csv into a DataFrame, df, and running the command `df['JobSatisfaction'].hist();` in my jupyter notebook.

I have done a bit more testing on the data and my tests were not matching the shape of the histogram. So I measured the proportion of each value in the column and then mapped them out in an Excel column chart. The shape looks different to the output of the `.hist()` function.

Can anyone share some light on this?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because when you call `df['JobSatisfaction'].hist()`, you are actually calling `hist(bins=10)` because the default value is `bins=10`. Therefore the value for 9.0s and 10.0s are aggregated into the same bin, results in the shape being different from what you expected.

When you run `df['JobSatisfaction'].unique()`, you should see there are 12 unique values, which are `NaN` and 0.0,1.0,...,10.0. Assuming you want to drop the `NaN`s, you would need to have a histogram with `bins=11` for each values to be counted in its "own" bin.

We can check this by running `df['JobSatisfaction'].hist(bins=11)`:

[image: Histogram (bins=11)]

Comment: Than you my comic book fan friend :)